# how to call new custom pipeline from existing pipeline failed?

Tags: build, pipeline

I try to run pipeline facing build failed error. so i want to create a new custom template from existing one without template file to run a pipeline.how to i do this ?

how to call a new pipeline from existing failed pipeline